# How to insert data to a table from a different controller in cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have just begun learning how to use cakePHP and I am finding it kind of tricky. I am currently trying to make a feature that adds data to table1 when a new row is added to table2.

I have been trying to use the loadModel function but i am not sure how to insert 2 pieces of data from table2 into table1 (the table that was loaded in) once I have table1 loaded in.

Any help that people can give would be greatly appreciated, also I am a beginner using cakePHP so the simpler the answer the better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `loadModel`, [`TableRegistry`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#using-the-tableregistry) should be used in CakePHP 3 applications. For that, add this line to the beginning of the file after namespace declaration.

```
...
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
...
```

And then, this line would bring **Model** object for you.

```
$memberProfilesModel = TableRegistry::get('MemberProfiles');
```

Now, you can continue with `newEntity()` and `save()` to add a new record in table.